function call: Matlab vs. Julia
Iam new in Julia and there is a question:
Function call in Matlab:
I have the opportunity, for example, to define an output array directly during the call
function **[output1, output2]** = Test (a, b, c)
   V_cube = a^3;
   output1 = V_cube;

   V_rectangle = a*b*c
   output2 = V_rectangle

end

Is there also a possibility to define an output array in Julia?
Kind regards!

That’s not an “output array”, that is “multiple output arguments”. — Just giving you the right terms to google.

ahh ... thank you ;)

The duplicate I linked was the first hit from Google — all you needed was the right terminology! ;) [which, by the way, is why we have these duplicate question links, they make it easier to find a solution, please don’t delete your question!]

Use a NamedTuple such as return (;output1, output2)
